# How to call methods on input of 'number' type?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and have an input with type=number:

```
<input type="number" min="1" value="1" id="amount-input" (click)="chooseStanding(standingspot.priceCategory)">
```

With (click), chooseStanding(standingspot.priceCategory) will be called every time the up or down button is clicked.

[image: Just for reference]

But is it possible to have different method calls based on which button was clicked? For example, if the down button was pressed a different method *removeStanding(standingspot.priceCateegory)* should be called and if the up button was pressed, *chooseStanding(standingspot.priceCategory)* should be called. I would really appreciate any help! :)

Comment: "*I'm new to HTML*" - that's not valid HTML. Are you using some kind of templating library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Dan's solution, but taking into consideration the exact difference between the previous and the next value.

Also, there is no need to store the previous value in a variable.

```js
const onIncrement = () => console.log('INCREMENT');
const onDecrement = () => console.log('DECREMENT');
const onChange = value => console.log('CHANGE TO: ', value);

const onChangeNumber = event => {
  const input = event.target;
  const newValue = parseInt(input.value);
  const oldValue = parseInt(input.getAttribute('old-value') || input.defaultValue) || 0;
  input.setAttribute('old-value', input.value);
 
  if (newValue === oldValue + 1)
    onIncrement();
  else
    if (newValue === oldValue - 1)
      onDecrement();
    else
      onChange(newValue);
}
```

```html
<input type='number' onchange='onChangeNumber(event)' defaultValue="0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the number value and on change you compare the new input value to the old input value and from there you can determine which button was pressed.

```js
var value = null;
var previousValue = null;
function chooseStanding() {
    var input = document.getElementById("amount-input");
    if (previousValue == null) {
         previousValue = input.value;
    }
    previousValue = value;
    value = input.value;
    if (previousValue > value) {
        // down button pressed
        console.log("down");
    }
    else if (previousValue < value) {
        // up button pressed
        console.log("up");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" value="1" id="amount-input" onchange="chooseStanding()">
```

Comment: When I enter some number larger than 1 using the keyboard, and the press the down button, your function still logs "up".

Comment: I see. I based it off of the button click exclusively. I’ll have to update it.

Comment: Oh yes true. Is there a way to fix this? But I think this is overall a really good solution :D

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. And notice that the `click` event also fires when you click anywhere else on the input, not just on the buttons. A number input is really about entering numbers, you only should use the number value in your event handlers. If you want to execute some actions when clicking on buttons, don't use a number input but two `<button>` elements.

Comment: Okay noted down. Thanks a lot!